# How do you get the yellow squares in the background?

Tags: fez

It won't let me get these squares and I don't know if there is like a special button but I don't know how to.

[image: FEZ game image]

Comment: Have you tried rotating?

Comment: Yes I have Pyritie

Comment: What's the name of that area again? Also, are you talking about the cube you're standing next to, or the cage?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. I just played through that room, and the similar ones in the area. The squares in the recessed areas can be picked up normally, by touching them, just like everywhere else in the game.

Fez is notoriously buggy, although this is a new one, even for me.

There are a few things to try:

- Restart the game and come back to this room
- You can go to "Help & Options", "Video Options", and set "Hardware Instancing" to "Off"

  - This has helped me with some video rendering issues with objects in the background
  - This option might only be available in version 1.12